# Setting the value of a cell in jqgrid not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am working with the spring MVC application. I am also using JQGrid plugin for the jquery. I am using the Jquery and JQGrid for the first time.

I am able to load the data successfully in jqgrid but after data is been loaded I want to change the value of the column named "hasApprovedByCorporate" in the jqGrid.I am also able to display the data of the mentioned column in the alert message as well.

Below is the jquery function that is responsible for loading the data inside the jqgrid and also provide you the snipet of all the css and java script files added inside the code(for jquery version reference).

```
   <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>             
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <%--<script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script> --%> 
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery/jquery.simplemodal.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <link href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/css/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/css/ui.jqgrid.preview.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/css/ui.multiselect.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/css/jquery.loadmask.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 


<script type=text/javascript>var jq = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script  type="text/javascript">


 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        loadMediaRequestDetails();
    });
 //function called when the this page gets loaded
 function loadMediaRequestDetails() {
     jq("#grid").jqGrid({       
     url:'/loadworkflowqueuedata.cvr?soeId=<%=request.getParameter("soeId")%>',   
     datatype: 'json',    
     mtype: 'GET', 
     colNames:[ 'RequestId','RequestorName','Corporate Affairs','Legal','Current Status','Request Type','Request Date','Event/Interview Date','Region'],       
     colModel:[
      {name:'requestId',index:'requestId',sortable: true,sorttype: 'number', width:100,editable:false,key:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10},formatter:showMediaDetailLink},
      {name:'requestor',index:'requestor',sortable: true, width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
      {name:'hasApprovedByCorporate',search:false, width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
      {name:'hasApprovedByRschMgmt',search:false,width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
      {name:'requestStatus', index:'requestStatus',sortable: true,width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
      {name:'requestType', index:'requestType',sortable: true,width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
      {name:'createDate',index:'createDate',search:false,sortable: true,sorttype: 'date',width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10},formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd/m/Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y'}},
      {name:'eventDate',index:'eventDate',sortable: true,sorttype: 'date',search:false,width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10},formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {srcformat: 'd/m/Y',newformat: 'd/m/Y'},searchoptions:{dataInit:datePick,searchOnEnter:false}},
      {name:'requestorRegion',index:'requestorRegion',sortable: true, width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}}
      ],
       postData: {     
       },    
       height: 'auto',       
       autowidth: true,    
       rownumbers: true,       
       pager: '#pager',       
       viewrecords: true,       
       sortorder: "asc",       
       emptyrecords: "Empty records",      
       loadonce: true,
       rowNum:10,
       loadComplete: function() {

          alert("complete function called1234");

          var rows= jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getRowData');
          alert(rows.length);
          for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
                var row=rows[i];
               alert(row['hasApprovedByCorporate']);//get the user_id column value
               if(row['hasApprovedByCorporate']=='true'){
                   alert("Corporate Affairs is true");
                   row['hasApprovedByCorporate']='Y';
               }
                  }

        },

       jsonReader : {    
           root: "rows",           
           repeatitems: false,
           page:"page",           
           total: "total",           
           records: "records", 
           cell: "cell",           
           id: "id"      
           }   
       });

     jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search: false,refresh:false});
     jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn",ignoreCase: true });

    };
</script>
```

I have to follow the simple algoritham to change the value of the cell

```
if (value of cell=='true'){
   value of cell='Y'
  set the new value back to jqgrid appropriate [row][column]
}
else{
    value of cell='N';
  set the new value back to jqgrid appropriate [row][column]
}
```

Here comes my question:

1.**But I don't know how to set the new value using the condition and display it back on the grid.**?

Please help me on this . I have gone through the several links but none of them works for me

Comment: it is possible to do. are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: @Vimalan Thanks for asking.I figure out the solution.